# Get public URL in index.html after build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, deployment, build

I have a reactjs app created with command `npx create-react-app my-app`, and I build my project using `yarn build`

package json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

Once I build the app index.html looks like below (It has absolute paths for all the static files),

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.af2bdfd5.js"></script>
<link href="/static/css/main.097da2df.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

I want to have those sources looks like below (need to give a public URL)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.af2bdfd5.js"></script>
<link href="http://localhost:3000/static/css/main.097da2df.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico">
```

I have tried adding `PUBLIC_URL` and `homepage` to package.json but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution,

I used `dotenv` to set the environment variable. Steps to implement the solution is given below.

1) Install `dotenv` package.

```
npm i dotenv
```

2) As early as possible in the application, require and configure dotenv.

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

3) Create a `.env` file in the root directory of the project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of `NAME=VALUE`.

```
PUBLIC_URL=http://192.168.8.100:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `%PUBLIC_URL%` in your link's href and it will fetch the files only if those files are present in the public folder.

Place your files in the `public` folder and lets assume the file is your icon which you want to access and its name is `icon.ico`

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icon.ico">`

You don't need to put the absolute url for your files and can just use `%PUBLIC_URL%` in index.html.

**Note**: You don't need to add PUBLIC_URL to `package.json`. It's assigned to the public folder already.

Comment: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/icon.ico">` is already there, but once I build the value of `%PUBLIC_URL%` is not added in static folder.

Comment: i think you could create a new `.env` file and assign a variable `APP_LINK = http://localhost:3000`. that would work.

Comment: also tried adding `.env` file to location of `package.json`. Assigned a variable PUBLIC_URL=http://localhost:3000. It didn't work

Comment: is 'static' directory inside public directory? i am asking this because the `public` directory is assigned to `localhost:3000' and if you try to access the child directories in public folder then only that is possible otherwise you cant access the other directories in your app.

Comment: you can give this last try -> `href="%REACT_APP_TEST_URL1%/icon.ico"` . and you can pass the env variable while you run your app as `REACT_APP_TEST_URL1=http://localhost:3000 npm start`

Comment: It's not a problem with `npm start`. once I build the react project, inside the created build directory, there is an index.html file. In that file it has all relative paths as mentioned in the question